# How to convert XML to YAML?

Tags: jekyll

I'm using a filter to pull XML from an RSS feed and then convert it to YAML to use in my page. It "works" but the issue is the YAML being returned is an unreadable string. How can I convert this into usable YAML?

Here is how I'm using the filter:

```
{%- assign endpoint = 'https://paragraph.xyz/api/blogs/rss/@dylsteck.eth' -%}
{%- assign data = endpoint | getrss -%}
```

getrss.rb:

```
require 'net/http'

module Jekyll
  module GetRSS

    def getrss(input)
      xml = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(input)).body
      Hash.from_xml(xml).to_yaml
    end

  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::GetRSS)
```

usage 1:

```
<script>console.log({{data.rss | jsonify}})</script>
```

output 1:

```
null
```

usage 2:

```
<script>console.log({{data | jsonify}})</script>
```

output 2:

```
---
rss:
  version: '2.0'
  xmlns:dc: http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/
  xmlns:content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/
  channel:
    title: Next in Tech
    link: https://paragraph.xyz/@dylsteck.eth
    description: undefined
    lastBuildDate: Thu, 13 Apr 2023 16:46:01 GMT
    docs: https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html
    generator: https://github.com/jpmonette/feed
    language: en
    image:
      title: Next in Tech
      url: https://storage.googleapis.com/papyrus_images/70c930a98f3fe404907f650409d5e4d8
      link: https://paragraph.xyz/@dylsteck.eth
    copyright: All rights reserved
    item:
    ...
    [more that I've omitted]
```

usage 3:

```
<script>console.log(typeof {{data.rss | jsonify}})</script>
```

output 3:

```
string
```

As you can see from the first usage it's not behaving as inspected. From the second usage you can see the "---" at the start which is odd. Then usage 3 confirms my suspicion that it was a string.

Answer (score 0):

As is tradition, I finally figured it out after creating this post. I needed to convert the YAML to a hash by loading it.

Updated `getrss.rb` file:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'
require 'yaml'

module Jekyll
  module GetRSS

    def getrss(input)
      xml = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(input)).body
      YAML.load(Hash.from_xml(xml).to_yaml)
    end

  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::GetRSS)
```